# I am trying to style images in a div class in css but it will not work for me. Why is this?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style a group of images or paragraphs in a certain way,

```css
.products {
  margin: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="products"> <img src="images/bodybutter1.jpg" style="width 250px; height: 300px; border-radius: 15px;" alt="bodybutter"> <img src="images/bodybutter1.jpg" style="width 250px; height: 300px; border-radius: 15px;" alt="bodybutter"> <img src="images/bodybutter1.jpg"
    style="width 250px; height: 300px; border-radius: 15px;" alt="bodybutter"> <img src="images/bodybutter1.jpg" style="width 250px; height: 300px; border-radius: 15px;" alt="bodybutter"> </div>
<div class="products">
  <img src="images/bodybutter1.jpg" style="width 250px; height: 300px; border-radius: 15px;" alt="bodybutter">
  <img src="images/bodybutter1.jpg" style="width 250px; height: 300px; border-radius: 15px;" alt="bodybutter">
  <img src="images/bodybutter1.jpg" style="width 250px; height: 300px; border-radius: 15px;" alt="bodybutter">
  <img src="images/bodybutter1.jpg" style="width 250px; height: 300px; border-radius: 15px;" alt="bodybutter">
</div>
```

Comment: html:<div class="products">
<img src="images/bodybutter1.jpg" style="width 250px; height: 300px; border-radius: 15px;" alt="bodybutter">
<img src="images/bodybutter1.jpg" style="width 250px; height: 300px; border-radius: 15px;" alt="bodybutter">
<img src="images/bodybutter1.jpg" style="width 250px; height: 300px; border-radius: 15px;" alt="bodybutter">
<img src="images/bodybutter1.jpg" style="width 250px; height: 300px; border-radius: 15px;" alt="bodybutter">
</div>

Comment: Please use the edit button bottom left of your question to add information on what you're trying to achieve. I have no idea how to help you with the current information present

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to target the img tag inside the parent instead of targeting the parent div. See code below:

```
.products img {
  margin: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px solid black;
}
```

You can use this to reduce code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Note: The first property you have inline is missing the semicolon and breaking your code. Which may be why you are not seeing those styles applied to your image elements.

Because you are reusing the same style for every image you should remove those inline styles using the style attribute and use CSS to target those elements.

Check out the code for context. Hope this helps!

```css
.products {
  margin: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px solid black;
}

.products img {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 15px;
  object-fit: cover;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="products">
  <img src="https://wtwp.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/placeholder-image.png" alt="bodybutter">
  <img src="https://wtwp.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/placeholder-image.png" alt="bodybutter">
  <img src="https://wtwp.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/placeholder-image.png" alt="bodybutter">
  <img src="https://wtwp.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/placeholder-image.png" alt="bodybutter">
</div>
<div class="products">
  <img src="https://wtwp.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/placeholder-image.png" alt="bodybutter">
  <img src="https://wtwp.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/placeholder-image.png" alt="bodybutter">
  <img src="https://wtwp.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/placeholder-image.png" alt="bodybutter">
  <img src="https://wtwp.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/placeholder-image.png" alt="bodybutter">
</div>
```